# Problem upgrading to 14.04 from 13.10

Tags: updates, system

I am trying to upgrade to 14.04 from 13.10, but I get the following message using the update manager:

```
E: The method driver /usr/lib/apt/methods/htto could not be found.
```

Interesting that there is an `htto` instead of `http`. Could that be the problem?

Comment: yes it should cause a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the output of ls /usr/lib/apt/methods/ should be similar to this:

```
bzip2  cdrom  copy  file  ftp  gpgv  gzip  http  https  lzma  mirror  rred  rsh  ssh  xz
```